# Is the Gradle version in Ubuntu 20.04 modified to support newer Java versions?

Tags: java, gradle

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, I am now on Java 11.0.9.1 and Gradle 4.4.1 (the latter being over two years old and long superseded by the time 20.04 was released). This combination works fine—despite the Gradle release notes starting that Java 11 support was only introduced with Gradle 5.0. `gradle --version` reports Gradle 4.4.1 and Java 11.0.9.1.

However, in one of my projects I use Gradle wrapper and have updated it to 4.4.1 as well. When invoked through Gradle wrapper, Gradle refuses to work with Java 11, despite the Gradle version being nominally the same as the installed one (4.4.1).

Does Ubuntu ship with a modified build of Gradle (e.g. with added support for newer Java versions)?

Comment: You might have better luck with the snap version of Gradle which is 6.6.1.  According to the `rmadison` script, Ubuntu 21.04 still has version 4.4.1-12

Comment: Or by running `gradle wrapper` and forcing the version of my choice—but that’s not my question. I really want to know if there is a difference between the locally installed version and the (nominally same) wrapper version.

Comment: Canonical puts a freeze on the apps before they release the LTS version.   The best place to get info about the app is to check its changelog.  `apt changelog gradle` The last thing I see is improving the detection of Java 9+, no mention of Java 11